# Urllib2 timeot doesn't work

Tags: python, http, python-2.7, web-scraping, urllib2

I go through a large list of urls with this procedure, i use multiple threads. However the first version where I use

```
myreq.fp._sock.fp._sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
```

to close the connection seems not to download all the data all the time.
On the other had when i instead use

```
#myreq.fp._sock.recv=None # hacky avoidance
```

sometimes connection to some sites hangs for a long time. More than a minute.

The code:

```
    useragent = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11'}
    request = urllib2.Request(url,None,useragent)
    try : 
        myreq = urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout = threadtimeout)
        html_code = myreq.read()
        myreq.fp._sock.fp._sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        #myreq.fp._sock.recv=None # hacky avoidance
        myreq.close()
    except Exception : 
        html_code = ""
```

Comment: *" connection to some sites hangs for a long time"* -- what do you mean? If you are talking about `TIME_WAIT` state then several minutes delay is normal (though nothing in your code should wait for it)

Comment: No it just doesn't respond as it should be. Anyway it works much better with request library.

Comment: *"it just doesn't respond as it should be"* -- how does it respond? How should it respond instead? What happens if you drop the `.shutdown()` call?

Comment: I am trying to scrape data from a page. But I am not getting response from some of these page for 4 minutes and the timeout is 10 sec. It is when i do not use .shutdown(). When i use it it downloads just a certain percentage of pages.

Comment: It seems it cannot handle pdf files, as some urls were links to pdfs'

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timeout for urllib2 from [Sockets and Layers](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#sockets-and-layers)

```
import socket

timeout = 10
socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)

myreq = urllib2.urlopen(request)
html_code = myreq.read()
```

Comment: Are you sure this solves the problem. I think that i used it beforeand didn't work but i wll give it try now.

Comment: @Brana not sure. just give a try. it wasn't mentioned in question, so I though i should suggest it.

Comment: are you familiar with how myreq.fp._sock.fp._sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR) works?

Comment: No, only `urllib` and `urllib2` unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This works much better as the request handles the connection closing automatically:

```
    useragent = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11'}

    request = urllib2.Request(url,None,useragent)
    try : 
        import requests
        response = requests.get(url, headers=useragent,timeout = threadtimeout)
        html_code = response.text
```